# Shift intercept of linear model such that only n-percent of the data is below the line

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, linear

I am in the following situation: I have a simple dataset with only two variables. I want to fit a linear model to the data. I then would like to shift the fitted line so much to the "bottom", that only a certain percentage of points falls below that line. I do not want to change the slope, only the y-intercept.

To illustrate the problem I have this data in `R`

```
library(ggplot2)
x = seq(1,10,length.out = 100)
y = x + rnorm(100, 10, 4)
lm0 = lm(y~x)
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(color="original"))+
  geom_abline(
    aes(
    intercept = coef(lm0)[[1]]-5,
    slope = coef(lm0)[[2]],
    color = "shifted"
    )
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("original" = "red", "shifted" = "blue"))
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

The issue now is, that the blue line is draw manually by a manual shift of of the intercept. I would like to automate this procedure and I just cannot wrap my head around a good solution. Maybe someone has an idea or a pointer to something.

Comment: Search for "quantile regression."

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I will have a look into this

Comment: Sounds like a programmatic exercise for the `uniroot` function. i.e. `uniroot(function(a){sum(y- a+b*x < 0) - 0.025}, lower=-100, upper=100)`

Comment: Thank a lot too:) I do not really know what this is doing, but I'll have a look into this!